# system error 1067 has occurred

Tags: mysql, xampp, mysql-error-1067

Ran into some troubles with XAMPP after MySQL wasn't starting.  So, I typed in the command prompt: 'net start MySQL', and it gave me this error message listed in the subject line.

Anyone know how to alleviate this?  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

This did the trick for me:

https://serverfault.com/questions/214435/error-1067-the-process-terminated-unexpectedly-when-trying-to-install-mysql-on/214846#214846

Of course, in this case, you have to **completely clean up the xampp folder**, which doesn't always happen. I guess I backed up the necessary files first (**data folder** from mysql folder and the **htdocs folder**). Uninstall XAMPP. Check the xampp folder for any content that remains and delete everything. You may want to reboot afterwards, just in case. Then reinstall XAMPP. Copy the backed-up folders back to their respective places, and hopefully, mySql will work again in XAMPP.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was enough to give full (absolute) paths to the `xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini` file. For example I changed `basedir` from `"/xampp/mysql/"` to: `"E:/xampp/mysql/"`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,11388,16051#msg-16051) or [this](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,11388,196627#msg-196627) might help you, if you're on windows

According to the posts, uninstalling then reinstalling with the --defaults-file option would fix the problem. Make sure to have the Services manager window closed, as this can cause weird bugs while trying to fix the problem

Comment: Do I do that from the command prompt, or within the Services box?

Comment: Every time I enter in 'mysqld' in the cmd prompt, I keep getting this error message below: "'mysqld' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Answer (score 0):

You can re-register your mysqld as a service and have it point to the my.cnf file with the proper data directory set: See http://www.jerrytravis.com/?p=533 for directions on how to do so. The article in the link refers to doing it when you've moved a Zend Server folder, however, the procedure will work for any msyql installation. Just cd to the proper directories.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered exactly the same problem. Here is the solution that work for my situation.
In my case I already installed xamp with mysql listening to port 3306, also I have mysql 5.0 listening to port 3307.
Then I am trying to install 64 bit mysql version 5.6 listening to port 3308, I already define it in my.ini, and then start cmd (must be open by run as administrator). My installation was "d:\mysql64", then go to that folder in cmd dialog box, then type "bin\mysqld --install mysql64 --default-file=d:\mysql64\my.ini". It was said that service installed successfully but when I try to start it by "net start mysql64", it give that error 1067.I also already try to install and reinstall several times by modifying my.ini but the problem persist.

The solution is =

1. remove the service by "bin\mysqld --remove mysql64"
2. reinstall the service by "bin\mysqld --install mysql64 --port=3308" ----> this is the solution
3. try to start mysql64 by window services or by "net start mysql64"

It will started successfully.

So in this case seems that --default-file argument was ignored by window service manager, because
I already define the port in my.ini but the service can not start and giving 1067 error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but on windows. What I've found is that the service was created under an unpriviledged account (in my case nt_authority). When I changed this to the "system" account, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think that at least a warning should be added to the product when the user tries to install MySQL on a path that contains whitespaces. This was the reason for the error "System error 1067 has occurred", which vanished after reinstalling MySQL under a path without blanks (used C:\Programs instead of C:\Program Files, which unfortunately appears in German Windows 10 as C:\Programme, i.e. w/o any spaces!).