# "net start" - System error 1067

Tags: sql-server, cmd, windows-services, windows-server-2003

How can I fix *system error 1067* which is the error I get while starting a service using the `net start` command in *Windows 2003 Server*?

```
C:\..>net start "<Service Name>" arg1 arg2
<Service Name> is starting ...

A system error has occurred.

System error 1067 has occurred.

The process terminated unexpectedly.
```

From similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4577356/640378), I gather that it is related to a database server. In my case, it is *SQL Server*. I see all the SQL Server related services up and running.

It seems to be a known problem, but I wasn't able to apply any of the online scenarios to my case.

Can anyone give me any suggestions how I can go about diagnosing this problem? Let me know if you need any other information that might be relevant.

**Other Details:**

- Microsoft SQL Server 2005

Comment: @MCND I tried some of the solutions on that page without success. I tried killing and restarting. This setup was running before, so I'm looking for ways to diagnose the problem and restore to normality.

Comment: Sorry, i misread the question. SQL server version? any information in server logs or windows logs?

Comment: @MCND Microsoft SQL Server 2005

Comment: @MCND Where do I find the server/windows logs? I was looking in the *Event Viewer*, not sure if that's right.

Comment: Yes, it is right. Also you can locate in the registry (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer\Parameters`) the location of the log files for the server.

Comment: What service are you actually trying to start?  That error could be caused by all sorts of different problems, not necessarily related to SQL Server.  The appropriate diagnostic steps depend on which service it is that is failing to start.

Comment: @MCND The logs in the Event Viewer seem to show no errors. Pretty much all are *Success Audits*. There's no *Parameters* sub-dir in the registry. However, I could find some logs in the _SQL Server Management Studio_. Nothing unusual here as well.

Comment: @HarryJohnston The service is part of a legacy application. It does some job scheduling. If you are curious, the job gets kicked off every few minutes and it monitors a folder for new files. If new files are found, it takes some pre-specified actions.

Comment: Unless the service in question uses SQL server, that's not the problem.  It is more likely to be a bug in the service itself.  Is it your own service, i.e., do you have the source code?

Comment: @HarryJohnston The same setup on the "Production" environment works. It's the "Development" environment setup that is throwing this error. Hence, it's not a bug in the service. Either way, it's a legacy system and the source code doesn't exist anymore. This application (in its entirety) uses *SQL Server*, however I can't say for sure if this service is also using SQL Server. On the prod environment's server, we have the same SQL Server services running.

Comment: Well, the service is terminating for *some* reason.  It might not be a bug per se, services are sometimes designed to intentionally terminate (rather than shutting down cleanly) when an error occurs, because that way the service manager can be configured to restart the service automatically.  You should be able to tell whether the service is connecting to the SQL server, or attempting and failing to connect, by examining the server's logs.  If that's not the problem, try using Process Monitor (available from the MS website) to see what the service is doing when it fails.

Comment: As a windows OS, this has nothing to do with SQL server. It's a pure service error when you try to start a service and it's shutting down over some configuration error or something else preventing it from running.
You think it's SQL server problem since the service you tried to run is:
"net start mysql". Right?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem a few hours ago involving Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Express, running on Windows 10 Professional. The resolution was to set the NTFS permissions on the data directory correctly. Specifically, to the existing permissions, I granted Full Control to the SID for NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER.

1. I obtained the SID by executing `PsGetsid64.exe MSSQLSERVER` in an elevated command prompt window. `MSSQLSERVER` is the name assigned to a default SQL Server instance.
2. I applied the permissions by executing `icacls f:\MSSQLServer_2017_Data /grant *S-1-5-80-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx:(F) /T`in the same elevated prompt.

After all that, icacls gives the following report on the data directory.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>icacls F:\MSSQLServer_2017_Data
F:\MSSQLServer_2017_Data NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER:(F)
                         BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
                         BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
                         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
                         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
                         NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)
                         NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)
                         BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
                         BUILTIN\Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)
```

In conclusion, you should be aware that, since I added the SID to the existing permissions, the final set of permissions may be more generous than necessary. However, since this is a development installation, I am not as concerned about protecting it as I would a production installation, so I haven't fine tuned the permissions further.